# broadcast to all other session except the one which broadcasted

Tags: atmosphere

I  am trying to use atmosphere,   I want  to broadcast msg for all the   resources except  for the  one  which  broadcasted  the msg, please advice how to exclude   a  resource.

In a  page on click of a link I call code to broadcast msg  and this same page  has  a  public method with @Subscribe annotation ,this method gets called  when  msg is broadcasted.  I want to broadcast msg to  all other sessions except  for  current session which  broadcasted , please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ExcludeSessionBroadcaster which comes with Atmosphere Runtime.